# jQuery .support() implementation

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, fade

Can someone take a look at the following plugin. I its a basic AJAX navigation plugin and it fades content into a div when menu buttons are pressed.  What would be the easiest way to *exclude* IE 6/7/8 from recognizing the fade effect? I just want IE to not see the fadeOut/fadeIn part of the plugin:

```
$(function() {

var newHash      = "",
    $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
    $pageWrap    = $("#page-wrap"),
    baseHeight   = 0,
    $el;



$("nav#footer").delegate("a", "click", function() {
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
    return false;
});

$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){

    newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

    if (newHash) {
        $mainContent
            .find("#guts")
            .fadeOut(200, function() {
                $mainContent.show().load(newHash + " #guts", function() {
                    $mainContent.fadeIn(200, function() {
                    });
                    $("nav#footer a").removeClass("current");
                    $("nav#footer a[href="+newHash+"]").addClass("current");
                });
            });
    };

});

$(window).trigger('hashchange');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since IE does not support cssFloat you can use jQuery `$.support` and issue the following conditional to detect if browser is IE  `if($.support.cssFloat) {....`

Comment: At that rate, you might as well just check for [`$.browser.msie`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser), since `cssFloat` has nothing to do with the fading.

Comment: jQuery will not longer be supporting `$.browser`. You need to use `$.support` instead. Read more at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Comment: @Hussein your statement should be `(!$.support.cssFloat)` because it returns **false** in IE versions below 9.